what is the error in my github action o is ngrok o is yml archive?
I have a similar problem but with a GitHub Actions workflow. I have spent 2 days trying to solve this problem.
Here's my workflow:
name: Testing Deploy Script

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Find and execute script
      run: |
        # Find the .sh file and execute it
        SCRIPT=$(find . -type f -name "*.sh" | head -n 1)
        if [ -f "$SCRIPT" ]; then
          chmod +x "$SCRIPT"
          ./"$SCRIPT"
          echo "Deployment successful: UniFi Controller is up! ✅"
        else
          echo "No bash script found in the repository."
          exit 1
        fi

    #- name: Download snap binary
    # run: |
    #  sudo apt install snapd

    - name: Download ngrok binary
      run: |
        curl -s https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com/ngrok.asc \
          | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ngrok.asc >/dev/null \
          && echo "deb https://ngrok-agent.s3.amazonaws.com buster main" \
          | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ngrok.list \
          && sudo apt update \
          && sudo apt install ngrok

    - name: Set ngrok authtoken
      run: |
        ngrok config add-authtoken 
      
    - name: Start ngrok tunnel[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/F00YeJOV.png)
      run: |
        ngrok http 8443 &
        sleep 3 # Wait for ngrok to initialize
        echo "Ngrok tunnel is now active"
        cat /dev/null
        
    - name: Keep workflow running for 5 minutes
      run: sleep 300 # 300 seconds = 5 minutes


I tried everything from installing it with snap but it asks me for permissions and I can't give them since it is a GitHub Actions runtime to fix the syntax error.
